# iOS 7 error Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x1568db40> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have issue in iOS 7 that does not appear in iOS 6.

I have a navigation controller that is displaying another navigation controller to add an employee.  This second controller is being presented modally.  When I dismiss the second controller either with a "Cancel" or "Done" button, I get an error.  Here is the error:

> QuickSchedule[880:60b] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view
>   controller  while a presentation
>   or dismiss is in progress!

I am using an unwind segue and dismissing from the first controller using the following relevant code.

This is in ScheduleViewController.m  (My main controller window)

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DoneEditing"]) {
        [[MyManager sharedManager] saveChanges];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

The connection in the connection inspector for the "Done" button is simply
"action -> [unwind done:]"

I had no errors before upgrading to Xcode 5.  This all started after upgrading Xcode and my storyboard to iOS 7.

I am getting same error in different spot in my app, but again, it's with a modally presented view controller.

I go from EmployeeViewController to AddEmployeeViewController modally.  I get the error again when I return from AddEmployeeViewController.

EmployeeViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"]) {
        AddEmployeeViewController *addController = [segue sourceViewController];
        if (addController.employee) {
            [[MyManager sharedManager] saveChanges];
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
        }
        if (![self.presentedViewController isBeingDismissed]) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CancelInput"]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Here is AddEmployeeViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"]) {
        if ([self.firstNameField.text length] || [self.lastNameField.text length]) {

            Employee *newEmployee = [[MyManager sharedManager] createEmployeeWithFirstName:self.firstNameField.text andLastName:self.lastNameField.text];
            [[MyManager sharedManager] addEmployeeToList:newEmployee];
            self.employee = newEmployee;
        }
    }
}
```

I am still learning, and I have looked for hours online and cannot find an answer to this. I have tried putting the "saving code" in a completion block. I put it back and tried using nil instead of NULL in the completion block argument. As you can see, I have nil in one spot on a completion block argument and NULL on another.  No matter what, the error keeps appearing.

Everything works as far a functionality, I just get this error logged to the console.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note:
I do not get this error with regular pushed navigation controllers.  This is only happening on dismissing modally presented view controllers.

Comment: Is you unwind segue triggered from a button, or is it connected directly to the view controller?

Comment: It is connected to UIBarButtonItems Done and Cancel on my AdEmployeeViewController, and UIBarButtonItem Done on the view controller that comes back to ScheduleViewController.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm surprised that you wouldn't see this same problem in previous versions of Xcode, because I think your problem is calling dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: in the "done" method. This should have been a problem in iOS 6 as well. The unwind segue does the dismissal for you, so you shouldn't call this method yourself. Try commenting it out, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: That really helped. I didn't know that the unwind segue handled that for me.

Comment: I had the same issue. My understanding of storyboards during iOS 6 came from "Your Second iOS App: Storyboards" at https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CreatingAddView/CreatingAddView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH6-SW1
In that tutorial (marked as "Not Recommended" since iOS 7), all the unwinds had dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: in them as well.

Comment: @ErikAllen, I'm not sure what's going on with that tutorial, because you normally wouldn't call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: in the controller you're going back to -- just like you wouldn't call presentViewController:animated:completion for a forward segue.

Comment: Actually, this answer is not always true. When you present a modal view controller from a UISplitViewController (Master or Detail), the unwind sequel does *not* do the dismissal for you, so you have to call dismissViewControllerAnimated in your unwind action method. But, even then, if you do have that call in your unwind action method, you will still get the error when running on a iPhone with iOS 7. I have tried wrapping the call in an if check:  if !segue.sourceViewController.isBeingDismissed() {...}, but isBeingDismissed() always returns false on iOS 7 (iPhone). Clustermuck.

Answer (score 7):

I had this very same problem in only iOS 7, too.

My problem was to call methods that works on the UI (like showing `UIAlertView` etc.) on the `viewWillAppear:` method. That was quite wrong because when one view was being *dismissed*, another view was *appearing* so both UI methods were being called.

I have moved my methods to `viewDidAppear:` method and the problem have been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Recheck your code. You have an animation that hasn't completely finished prior to firing another animation transition. I had the same issues and tracked it down to multiple animations slightly overlapping. Set `dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Okay, I did that, and you were right, the error went away.  But now the ViewController just vanishes and it doesn't look right.  The code in `ScheduleViewController.m` is the only place I see that particular animation being called.  Same thing in `EmployeeViewController`.

I really want the View Controller to slide down when done.

Answer (score 0):

here is the real answer to this question..! most of the time you programmer don't pay attention to events enum in the apple iOS sdk... if you use events like this [ UIControlEventAllEvent ] on a     [UIButton]  and run a [dismissViewControllerAnimated] note that the [ UIControlEventAllEvent ] contains lots of other events and you are dismissing the view before it finishes all other events inside the enum type of [ UIControlEventAllEvent ] !! so the guys if you just want a click on the button just use [UIControlEventTouchUpInside] and it will give you this error!!!

Answer (score 0):

Warnings of this type specific to iOS7 and not iOS6 do occur in other situations. In my case it was in relation to the dismissal of an email alert. I only had to add the conditional structure in the method below with iOS7.

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if(![[self modalViewController] isBeingDismissed])
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```