# Troubleshooting unwind segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Are there any tips and tricks for troubleshooting unwind segues?

I've had trouble with them not happening, or getting "*unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x??????*" errors. I've also gotten the warning “*Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!*”

Answer (score 5):

If the segue isn’t happening at all, make sure that the destination view controller doesn’t have a `canPerformUnwindSegueAction:` that is blocking it. It's a stupid error, but it happens if you don't have the proper logic for multiple segues.

If the unwind is breaking on something like "*-[MyViewController unwindToLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x??????*" then that implies you have a `canPerformUnwindSegueAction:` that is saying YES when it shouldn’t. You should only have it say YES to segues that actually exist within the `UIViewController`, because this could get called for ALL segues in the application, not just the ones in your view controller.

If you are getting the warning "*Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!*" then you are probably calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:` within your unwind segue. This is not needed with iOS7 onward. Older documentation that has since been marked as obsolete recommended this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906061/594602 for more information.